# How to add dart-define in build.gradle on a Flutter Plugin?

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-plugin, flutter-module

I have the following app structure:

```
- Main app (Android native)
 - Flutter module (aar)
  - Flutter plugin
```

The main Android App uses a Flutter module that contains some Flutter plugins.
One of this plugins requires a set of `dart-define` variables.

I could add the `--dart-define` argument on Flutter module AAR build, but there's some internal factors that makes this option not so good.

So, my question is, there's a way to add this `dart-define` settings inside the Flutter plugin (in the gradle scripts)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I found what you are looking for, once refer to this link https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add Dart define variables to your Flutter plugin through Gradle scripts.

In `build.gradle` file of your Flutter plugin module Add the below code to the android section of the file:

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_DART_DEFINE_VAR", 
    "\"my_dart_define_value\""
        ...
     }
    }
```

In your Flutter plugin Dart code, you can access the value of the build config field,

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

    const String myDartDefineVar = String.fromEnvironment('MY_DART_DEFINE_VAR', 
    defaultValue: 'default_value');

    // Example usage
    Future<String> getAssetContent(String assetPath) async {
      return await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);
    }
```

The `String.fromEnvironment` method will retrieve the value of the `MY_DART_DEFINE_VAR` build config field and assign it to the `myDartDefineVar` constant. If the build config field is not defined, it will use the default value `default_value`.

You can use the `myDartDefineVar` constant in your Flutter plugin code as needed.

Remember that you will need to rebuild your Flutter plugin module and update the `AAR` file in your main Android app to use the updated plugin with the new Dart define variables.

Comment: Any idea how this work for `--dart-define-from-file`